# issue with FindOne() mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to see if the user name is in the db but I'm getting the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

on this line of code:

if ( User.findOne({ username: $scope.username } function(err,doc){ if (doc) {return false; }})) {                   $this.signup();                 }

I don't see where an ) is missing

Comment: That's because your formatting doesn't let you see anything. Use proper formatting, use a linter.. Life will be much better

Comment: I don't know about mongoose but where should be `User.findOne(` its closing `)`? before that `function` maybe? it's messy...

Answer (score 0):

figured it out missing comma before the function:

if ( User.findOne({ username: $scope.username }, function(err,doc){ if (doc) {return false; }})) { $this.signup(); }

in case this helps anyone else